# any subgroup is a union of normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abstract group, and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$, then can $A$ be written as an union of $A_\alpha$, $\alpha\in I$, where $A_\alpha$ are normal subgroup of $G$?

Thanks!

Comment: Only if every subgroup of $G$ is normal.

Comment: There are groups with no non-trivial normal subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $G=S_3$.
Then $H=\{1,(12)\}$ is a subgroup which is not normal.
Clearly, $H$ cannot be written as a union of normal subgroups of $G$ as the only normal subgroups of $G$ are $1,G$ and $\{1,(123),(132)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ that can be written as a union of normal subgroups.

Then for every $x\in A$ there is some normal subgroup $N_x$ such that $x\in N_x\subseteq A$.

Then for every $x\in A$ and every $g\in G$ we find that: $$gxg^{-1}\in N_x\subseteq A$$

So actually it is proved by this that $A$ is a *normal* subgroup.

Conclusion: only normal subgroups of $G$ can be written as a union of normal subgroups.